# Stop request execution at certain point on Golang iris

Tags: go, go-iris

I have written a service I'm currently facing an issue where I want to stop the request cycle at a certain point and a return something to client side. 
I have used methods like `ctx.EndRequest()` `ctx.StopExecution()` but it keeps execute until the handler method finishes.

```
if aff.Status != StatActive {
        //Affiliate Not active exception
        err := errors.NewAffiliateNotActiveError(ctx)
        pc, fn, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        log.Printf("[error] in %s[%s:%d] %v", runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), fn, line, err)
        ctx.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        ctx.StopExecution()

    }
```

Like above when that condition triggered I want to stop execution equivalent of a throw exception. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Best advice is to not use iris at all. You should ask the author of iris. (And if you really want help here on SO you must post the relevant code, stripped to a bare minimum.)

Comment: @Volker I've updted the question and  added a code snippet.

Comment: "keeps execute until the handler method finishes" sounds like you're not returning from the function. Come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want concrete advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement if you want the handler execution to stop.